# Position to the right when it's float to the left

Tags: css, position

I have a menu and a logo on the header, and I am struggling to make the logo to be at the far edge of the left side of the website and the menu to the edge of the right side.

The problem is, when both of them are displayed as inline-block which means they are going to float to the default orientation which is left, I can't figure out a way to change this, please help.

**Here's the CSS code:**

```
/*Header*/
.wrapperHeader{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.content{
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}   

.header-logo, #logoImage{
    width: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*Main Menu*/
.header-menu{
    width: 690px;
    max-width: 100%;

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#MainMenu li{
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 0px;
}
```

**Note:** in the html, the logo is in a section and the menu is in anther section and both of them are inside a divide.

HTML code:

```
<header>
            <div class="wrapperHeader">
                <div class="content">
                    <section class="header-logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img id="logoImage" src="assets/elements/logo.png" alt="LOAI Design Studio Logo"/></a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="header-menu">
                        <nav id="MainMenu"> 
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li id="PortfolioMenu"><a id="Portfolio" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                                    <ul class="subMenu">
                                        <li><a href="web-design.html">Web Design</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="visual-identity.html">Visual Identity</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Get In Touch</a></li>
                                <li><a class="getStartedButton" href="get-started.html">Get Started</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <a href="#" id="SmartMenu">Menu<p id="SmartMenu-logo">LOAI Design Studio</p></a>
                        </nav>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: I believe we need your html/mark up in order to recreate your problem

Comment: if you use inline-block , you may be interrested in the use of text-align:justify . see http://t.co/K4yDHMUEF5

Comment: Just added the HTML code, thanks!

Comment: for info: from your inline-block display: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lyran

Comment: I tired to flat the menu to the right, but when I apply float right on the menu, the a's as in the menu links flip! so the Home link start from the right rather starting from the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've edited your CSS code, so you can try this

```
/*Header*/
.wrapperHeader{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}   

.header-logo, #logoImage{
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}

/*Main Menu*/
.header-menu{
    width: 690px;
    float: right;
}

#MainMenu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#MainMenu li{
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

li#PortfolioMenu{
    padding: 0;
}

li#PortfolioMenu > a{
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

ul.subMenu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover ul.subMenu{
    display: block;
}
```

I've used **float:left;** for the logo, **float:right;** for the header-menu, removed **display:inline-block;** and did some other fixes ...

Hope this will help you ...

Comment: Thank you, that didn't really solve it completely, but it opened my eyes on something that will maybe help! I am trying now and hope to get it right, thanks lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would float logo section left, float menu section right and then clear the wrapper using clear:both. Remove the inline-block for this to work properly.